# Add a class to HTML document in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs

I need to add the class `homePage` to the HTML document when I'm on the home page of my site.

I'm using AngularJS, and not sure how to add a conditional class to the HTML element itself.

```
<html>  <-- I need to add a class here. ng-class won't work since it's outside of the app.
<head>
  ... 
  bunch of required stuff 
  ...
</head>
<body>
    <main ng-app="myApp" class="myApp">
      <div class="viewContainer" ng-view>
      </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be able to apply `ng-app` to the `html` element.. is there some reason you can't do that?

Comment: Even if I did, I don't believe `ng-class` would work outside of the `ng-controller`.  Remember, I need to only apply this class when it's using the homeController.

Comment: Oh yeah, `ng-class` would work but you wouldn't have a scope there unless you used `$rootScope`. You could make another controller, and attach that to the `html` element via `ng-controller` and then `ng-class` would work. Would you be happy with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to at least move your `ng-app` property to the `html` element if you want to use `ng-class` on it. I think one of the nicer ways to solve the problem would be to do this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TopController" ng-class="{'homePage': atHome}">
```

Then your `TopController` can do:

```
app.controller("TopController", function($rootScope, $scope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, next, current) {
    $scope.atHome = ($location.path() === "/home");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar not to long ago but for the body, but should work just as well for the html, providing you move the `ng-app` to the html instead.

First we create a `service` and a `directive`. The service gets injected to whatever controller needs to change and the directive gets applied to the element that gets changed.

```
var BodyClasses = angular.module('BodyClasses', []);

// the service
BodyClasses.factory('bodyClassesApi', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    return {
        add: function(cls){
            $rootScope.$emit('body-classes-add', cls);
        },
        remove: function(cls){
            $rootScope.$emit('body-classes-remove', cls);
        },
        toggle: function(cls){
            $rootScope.$emit('body-classes-toggle', cls);
        }
    };
}]);

// the directive
BodyClasses.directive('bodyClasses', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            $rootScope.$on('body-classes-add', function(e, cls){
                element.addClass(cls);
            });

            $rootScope.$on('body-classes-remove', function(e, cls){
                element.removeClass(cls);
            });

            $rootScope.$on('body-classes-toggle', function(e, cls){
                element.toggleClass(cls);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Include the the `BodyClasses` module when you create your module. Then set your `html` element to be

```
<html ng-app="myApp" body-classes>
```

Now within your controller

```
app.controller('MyController', ['bodyClassesApi', function(bodyClassesApi){
    bodyClassesApi.add('some-class');
    bodyClassesApi.remove('some-class');
    bodyClassesApi.toggle('some-class');
}]);
```

You could skip the service and instead inject rootScope and just emit those events, but I generally prefer this style.